# Google play services | Cloud saved game | Fetch friends game state

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-cloud-save

I am working on unity3d based Farm game using Google play services Cloud saved game.

- I need to fetch my friends game state to visit their farms.
- Is it possible using Google play game services??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse.com might be a good solution for this. It's a cloud database (with support for cloud logic), integrated well with programming languages (including Unity/C#/Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

No, the saved game data is stored on a per user basis for each game, so there is no way to access another player's game state.  There is more detailed information on how the storage is accounted for on the developer web page: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames

Comment: Thanks for reply..Any future plan to add support of getting another player's game state?

Comment: Good question! I'll pass it along.